# Identify the language in Virgin Black's Walk Without Limbs

Tags: lyrics, meaning, language

The lyrics to the song *Walk Without Limbs* by Virgin Black from the album Sombre Romantic are (according to my searches):

```
Shei masa fum de ma
Walk without limbs
Shei masa fum de ma
Walk through my soul.
```

What language is "shei masa fum de ma" in (and what does it mean)?

The only "answer" I've found claims it means "manifest of the soul", but there's no source for that claim, or even a language, so I'm rather skeptical.

I saw someone claim it was taken from a Dead Sea scroll, so Hebrew? But I haven't been able to confirm that. Obviously it's not in the Hebrew script, and for all I know the Romanization is all wrong.

Trying to look up the individual words to identify a possible language has yielded nothing, but there's not much to work with.

Comment: It could just be made-up, to sound mysterious - which it succeeds at very well... Google translate and Bing translate certainly can't make much sense of it.

Comment: @Angst It's possible. It's also possible that Google/Bing doesn't recognize it because it's in the wrong script (Roman/Latin instead of Hebrew, for example), or maybe the lyrics you find online were transcribed by someone listening to the song and they got the spelling completely wrong. But hopefully someone recognizes it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the lyric is based on a literal latinised translation of phonetic Hebrew, the closest approximation of this lyric, which makes any sense to me in the context of the song, is:

> Struggling/dragging with a great burden.

I can't point to any definitive source as this "translation", in its loosest sense, is from half remembered schooling and some rather crude online translation. Happy to be corrected.

Comment: Can you provide your sentence in Hebrew?

Comment: It was something like: מא דע כוצ מסע. סהעי. It wasn't a direct translation, it was loose,  more based on what I could work out from the context of the lyric.  As stated above, happy to be corrected as I am by means any form of scholar in this. It could easily be translated as "making a harsh journey". I'm not too sure of pronouns or prepositions. This all depends on the lyric being a latinised rendering of Hebrew in the first place and not just made up words.